# Generic Way to Get MethodInfo For Methods Using Xml Documentation Member.Name

Tags: c#, system.reflection, xml-documentation, methodinfo

I am trying to get the System.Reflection.MethodInfo metadata of a method using the member name from an Xml Documentation file entry.

Here is the basic code. I have left out the boilerplate to get the values from the Member.name string for brevity.

```
// The following variables are all parsed out of the 'name' string from the 
// XML documentation for each entry (from 1st example below):
// Member: "ToInt"
// Namespace: "Library.Extensions"
// ClassName: "ConvertExtensions"    
// AssemblyToDocument: Library 
// ParameterArray: "System.String,System.Int32"

// Uses the GetMethod() method with the parameter 'types' overload
// as there can be multiple signatures for a particular Method name.  

string typeName = $"{Namespace}.{ClassName}, {AssemblyToDocument}";        
var types = ToTypeArray(ParameterArray);
MethodInfo methodInfo =  typeName.GetMethod(Member, types);


private Type[] ToTypeArray(string[] typeNames)
{
    var types = new List<Type>();

    foreach (string name in typeNames)
    {
        types.Add(Type.GetType(name));
    }
    return types.ToArray();
}
```

This works fine for methods with only one signature or with a few simple signatures like below.

```
<member name="M:Library.Extensions.ConvertExtensions.ToInt(System.String,System.Int32)"></member>

<member name="M:Library.Extensions.ConvertExtensions.ToBool(System.String)"></member>
```

But breaks down for more complicated examples, such as an method overloads. The
strings from the doc XML for the more complicated types are just not parsable by Type.GetType(string).

```
<member name="M:Library.Extensions.ConvertExtensions.ToBool(System.String,System.String,System.Boolean)"></member>

<member name="M:Library.Extensions.IEnumerableExtensions.ElementInOrDefault``1(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable{``0},System.Int32)"></member>
```

Currently, I can get the MemberInfo for about half of the entries in my xml documentation file.

Is there a reliable, generic way to get the MethodInfo object using the member.name from an XML document file?

Comment: I don't understand what type of your `Member` object? If it's string, just pass a method name `ToBool`, `ToBoolNullable`,... Then you can get the MethodInfo object.

Comment: I updated the question a bit to hopefully explain better. I left out the boilerplate to get the string values parsed out of the xml documentation string.

Answer (score 0):

This topic might be clearer as `How to get MethodInfo with many overloading functions and complicated parameter`.

I'm assuming that you did parsed XML documentation successful and got the string like this

```
NetCoreScripts.StackOverFlow.ReflectionTopic.MyObject(System.String,System.String,System.Boolean)
```

Over there you can use any separator method to split into 2 elements:

First is: `NetCoreScripts.StackOverFlow.ReflectionTopic.MyObject`

Second is array of: `System.String`, `System.String`, `System.Boolean` (3 params must be the same order)

```
    private static Type[] ToTypeArray(string[] typeNames)
    {
        var types = new List<Type>();

        foreach (string name in typeNames)
        {
            types.Add(Type.GetType(name));
        }
        return types.ToArray();
    }
```

I reuse your ToTypeArray and create a model

```
namespace NetCoreScripts.StackOverFlow.ReflectionTopic
{
    public class MyObject
    {
        public void DoMore(int parameter) { }
        public void DoMore(string str1, string str2, bool bool1) { }
        public void DoMore(string str, int num) { }
        public void DoMore(List<string> parameter) { }
        public void DoMore(List<string> parameter, int param) { }
        public void DoMore(List<List<string>> parameter, bool? nullableBool, bool isTrue) { }
    }
}
```

Main calling method will be

```
    public static void GetMyMethod(Type type, string[] arr)
    {
        var parammeters = ToTypeArray(arr);
        var method = type.GetMethod("DoMore", parammeters);
        Console.WriteLine(method.Name);
    }

    public static void MainFunc()
    {
        var type = Type.GetType("NetCoreScripts.StackOverFlow.ReflectionTopic.MyObject");
        GetMyMethod(type, new string[] { "System.Int32" });
        GetMyMethod(type, new string[] { "System.String", "System.String", "System.Boolean" });
        GetMyMethod(type, new string[] { "System.String", "System.Int32" });
        GetMyMethod(type, new string[] { "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String]]" });
        GetMyMethod(type, new string[] { "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String]]", "System.Int32" });
        GetMyMethod(type, new string[] { "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String]]]]", "System.Nullable`1[[System.Boolean]]", "System.Boolean" });
    }
```

To know exactly there name, I suggest using full name on pair testing, write and read Xml would be easier

```
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(bool?).FullName); 
        //System.Nullable`1[[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]

        Console.WriteLine(Type.GetType("System.Nullable`1[[System.Boolean]]").FullName);
        //For shorter
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for putting some thought into this. Aren't you just pulling some of the specific signatures for some possible types? What I am looking for is a general solution that will work most or all entries in an Xml documentation file.

Comment: I worked on the title to make it a little clearer what it is I am looking for.

Comment: @WillC I'm using the string of type from system which it could understand. It depends on how your Member.Name gives exact string, such as `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String]]`

Comment: For generic if you don't want to care about the string, the writer input of xml should be extract from `typeof(bool?).FullName` as well, instead of typing manual. But it requires the same platform, cross ex. .NetCore and.NetFramework might get difference.

Comment: I have parsed out the type name from the member.name string, so I can derive type with no problem.The problem is then relating the XML documentation method name back to the MethodInfo, as the type strings that the XML documentation produces are sometimes, but not always, parsable to the type they represent.